# SQL Tables Joining issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Table 1 and 2. I want to update information at Table 1 based on Table 2. 
For example, correct AA in table 1 from 10 to 30.

What quires should I write?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Mysql......................

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. It's not as obvious as you might think.

Comment: `update a
  set a.Column2 = b.Column2 
  from Table1 a inner join Table2 b on a.Column1 = b.Column1` or so?

Not quite as familiar with MySQL (thus is why I'm not putting this as an answer) but this is how it'd be done in MS SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I have two database right now, Database 1 is the master version with 2 columns. Database 2 is the updating version where constantly change by people. What I want to achieve is that update the information in Database 1 by mapping them in Database 2. Do I explain myself clearly?

Comment: @user2366842 I still want to keep the information which is not in Table 2.

Comment: What I've added would (once again, in MS SQL at least) leave you with AA = 30, BB=20, CC=20, DD=10 in table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to do a join from what I can tell, but instead you should do an update. It does get a bit more complicated when you're using data from another table instead of feeding raw data straight into the query.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1,
     Table2 t2
SET t1.num = t2.num
WHERE t1.name == t2.name;
```

not the exact code of course because the question and tables are somewhat vague but I believe this is the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try an update with a join.

UPDATE TABLE1 a 
   JOIN TABLE2 b 
     ON a.join_colA = b.join_colA
   SET a.numberColumn = b.numberColumn

Here column join_colA is your first column numberColumn would be your other value column.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in 3 steps

Step 1: Join the tables
Step 2: Update the null values from table 1
Step 3: Drop the unnecessary column

```
Select A.*, B.Column2 as column3 from A
left join B
on A.Column1=B.Column1


update table1
set column3= column2

alter table table1
drop column column2
```

Figure out the syntax errors that you may encounter